# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

So, I tried to add a new lines on my query, but unfortunately I've got this error :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
>   career_solutions

What I've done to add :

```
career_solutions_certification as certification,

INNER JOIN certification
ON career_solutions_certification.id = career_solutions.certification

 $career_solution->topic_certification_id = $request['topic_certification_id'];$career_solution->save();
```

*Here is my code*

```
$career_solutions_data = DB::select(" 
SELECT 
career_solutions.id,
career_solutions.user_id,  
career_solutions.subject, 
career_solutions.date, 
career_solutions.public, 
career_solutions.views, 
career_solutions.optional, 
career_solutions.on_offer, 
users.username, 
users.profile_picture, 
categories.category, 
categories.category_url, 
categories.color, 
career_solutions_categories.category as sub_category,
career_solutions_format.category as event_format,
career_solutions_certification.category as certification,

FROM career_solutions 

INNER JOIN categories 
ON categories.id = career_solutions.topic_category_id 

INNER JOIN career_solutions_format
ON career_solutions_format.id = career_solutions.topic_format_id

INNER JOIN certification
ON career_solutions_certification.id = career_solutions.certification

INNER JOIN career_solutions_categories 
ON career_solutions_categories.id = career_solutions.topic_subcategory_id 

INNER JOIN users 
ON users.id = career_solutions.user_id 


INNER JOIN privacy_settings 
ON privacy_settings.user_id = users.id 

WHERE users.deleted_at IS NULL 
AND ( 
(privacy_settings.career_solutions = 0 AND public = 1 ) 
OR (users.id IN ( 

SELECT contacts.contact_id 
FROM contacts 
WHERE contacts.user_id = $id 
) 
) 
) 

OR users.id = $id 

ORDER BY date desc limit 5000 
");
```

My table is `career_solutions_certification`/ column `id` and `category`.

Comment: You have an extra comma in `career_solutions_certification.category as certification,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
career_solutions_certification.category as certification
```

May be without - ,

Comment: thank you :)So the last one should be without comma everytime?

Comment: yes. Comma is incorrect in last column in your query

Answer (score 0):

After selecting columns there is additional comma

```
Wrong : career_solutions_certification.category as certification**,**



Correct : career_solutions_certification.category as certification
```